# Wrap text around BOTH sides of an image

Tags: ckeditor

After inserting an inline image, there are options to wrap the text on the left OR on the right of the image. I need to be able to wrap the text on BOTH sides of the image.

I selected the image and clicked the text wrap button - only 2 options are availbale: wrap left or wrap right. I need ot be able to wrap on both sides!

Comment: You can do in ckeditor only those things that you can do in plain html, because ckeditor generates html behind the scenes. This is not possible with normal html.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.